# Counting the number of set bits in a number

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

The problem statement is:

Write an efficient program to count number of 1s in binary representation of an integer.

I found a post on this problem [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/) which outlines multiple solutions which run in log(n) time including Brian Kernigan's algorithm and the gcc `__builtin_popcount()` method.

One solution that wasn't mentioned was the python method: `bin(n).count("1")` 
which also achieves the same effect. Does this method also run in log n time?

Comment: It runs in O(n) time, where `n` is the total number of bits.

Comment: Unlikely. The efficient solutions are designed specifically for counting bits, but the `count()` function operates on any string and can't use those optimizations.

Comment: At least O(n) time. The `.count("1")` has to visit each bit. Is `bin(n)` also linear?

Comment: @Robᵩ But there are log(n) bits in bin(n) by definition of binary representation

Comment: I think everyone has been assuming that `n` is the number of bits in the input, not the numeric value of the input.

Comment: I'd use `n & 2**math.ceil(log(n, 2)) -1`

Comment: The most efficient way is probably the lookup table. It's O(1) unless you have to deal with multi-precision numbers.

Comment: @Barmar Wouldn't the lookup table require O(n) space?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: find a middle ground; create a table for all possible values of a byte. Producing bytes for an integer is cheap.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I got this question in an interview though, would it matter if I just used the count method, or should I implement one of the more efficient ways to count set bits? Since doing so might complicate the solution

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 I'd discuss your thinking with the interviewer. Generally it is your thinking process that matters, not if you memorised the most efficient method of counting bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are converting the integer to a string, which means it'll have to produce N `'0'` and `'1'` characters. You then use `str.count()` which must visit *every character* in the string to count the `'1'` characters.

All in all you have a O(N) algorithm, with a relatively high constant cost.

Note that this is the same complexity as the code you linked to; the integer `n` has log(n) bits, but the algorithm still has to make N = log(n) steps to calculate the number of bits. The `bin(n).count('1')` algorithm is thus equivalent, but *slow* as there is a high cost to produce the string in the first place.

At the cost of a table, you could move to processing integers *per byte*:

```
table = [0]
while len(table) < 256:
    table += [t + 1 for t in table]

length = sum(map(table.__getitem__, n.to_bytes(n.bit_length() // 8 + 1, 'little')))
```

However, because Python needs to produce a series of new objects (a `bytes` object and several integers) this method never quite is fast enough to beat the `bin(n).count('1')` method:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> import timeit
>>> table = [0]
>>> while len(table) < 256:
...     table += [t + 1 for t in table]
...
>>> def perbyte(n): return sum(map(table.__getitem__, n.to_bytes(n.bit_length() // 8 + 1, 'little')))
...
>>> def strcount(n): return bin(n).count('1')
...
>>> n = int(''.join([choice('01') for _ in range(2 ** 16)]))
>>> for f in (strcount, perbyte):
...     print(f.__name__, timeit.timeit('f(n)', 'from __main__ import f, n', number=1000))
...
strcount 1.11822146497434
perbyte 1.4401431040023454
```

No matter the bit-length of the test number, `perbyte` is always a percentage slower.

Comment: But there are log(n) charactes in bin(n). Thus, count will work for O(len(bin(n))) = O(log n)

Comment: @DmitryTorba: yes, I was already editing in an explanation there; the article linked is rather disingenuous in that the algorithm there is just as linear; just because the integer `n` has `log(n)` bits doesn't make the algorithm to count *bits* suddenly logarithmic.

Comment: So the `count()` method is going to be linear because the time to create and append to the string will dominate asymptotically? And also, wouldn't the algorithms in the article still be log(n) since there are log(n) bits?

Comment: @MartijnPieters In my tests, your table way is consistently significantly slower than the `bin(n).count('1')` way... (about factor 1.3 slower for large strings, and about factor 2.6 slower for short strings, even when I prepare the table ahead of timing).

Comment: @StefanPochmann I didn't do any performance tests myself (lack of time), so I appreciate the effort there. How large are the integers you tested with? Does switching to `'big'` for endianness make any difference?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 there are always log(integer) bits to process, but since counting bits is the whole point we always use that as the starting point when comparing bit -counting algorithms.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Up to 2**26 bytes large. No, with `'big'` it looks the same.

Comment: @StefanPochmann crumbs, then I overestimated the efficiency of either `int.to_bytes()` or `int.bit_length()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nah, `n.to_bytes(n.bit_length() // 8 + 1, 'little'))` alone takes about 30%-40% of your total time for small ints (like up to 2\*\*4 bytes) and only about 3% for strings of 2\*\*10 bytes or longer. Most of your time is spent in the generator and `sum`.

Comment: Perhaps `sum(map(table.__getitem__, n.to_bytes(n.bit_length() // 8 + 1, 'little')))` would improve on that then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks maybe slightly faster, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you are trying to count the number of set bits of `n`. On *Python* typical implementations, `bin` will compute the binary representation in `O(log n)` time and `count` will go through the string, therefore resulting in an overall `O(log n)` complexity.

However, note that usually, the input parameter of algorithms is the "size" of the input. When you work with integers, this corresponds to their logarithm. That's why the current algorithm is said to have a *linear* complexity (the variable is `m = log n`, and the complexity `O(m)`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it would be linear. If the input size is m (meaning there are m bits) and m can be found by log n bits (where n is the decimal representation of a number), then shouldn't the runtime be log(n)?

Comment: loremlpsum171: The runtime is a `O(log(n))` and it is also a `O(m)`. When we say an algorithm is "linear", "quadratic" or "logarithmic" without precising the variable, the default one is the _size_ of the input. Here it is `m`, not `n`.   If this algorithm was said to be _logarithmic_, it would mean its complexity is a `O(log(m))`, i.e. a  `O(log(log(n)))`.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand what you're saying. So then it would be best just to say the algorithm is linear as to avoid misinterpretation?

Comment: loremlpsum1771: provided that the person you're talking to is aware of this rule, yes (in fact, it comes from the theoretical meaning of the time complexity of an algorithm). But a lot of people are making such mistakes today, so I think the safest way to indicate the complexity of your algorithm "in everyday's life" is to precise the meaning of your variable (e.g. "I'm counting the number of bits of `n`, and my algorithm has a `O(log n)` time complexity").